# Detecting Keyboard Hooks

Tags: windows, security, windows-vista, keyboard, hook

Is there a way to detect which programs or modules are listening to a keyboard hook? By Sysinternals maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This blog post has instructions:
http://zairon.wordpress.com/2006/12/06/any-application-defined-hook-procedure-on-my-machine/

Comment: some other links as that one didn't work for me on win7, over here http://stackoverflow.com/a/15676830/107537

Comment: Your images are missing.

Answer (score 1):

It largely depends on what level of abstraction are you obtaining your key presses.
For maximum detection you could use hardware directly or go as low as possible (some hooks work at HW driver-level).

For security purposes, you could also use a virtual keyboard - hooks would have to be targeted specifically at your application to simulate key presses.

Answer (score 0):

Nope.  You would likely have to hook into SetWindowsHookEx() itself in order to detect that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can, there's no GetWindowsHook function that would return the hook(s). Also, I'm under the impression that the main keyboard processing routine is hooked through SetWindowsHookEx(), so even if there are no hooks, there's at least one, Windows itself.

Comment: Thanks;
I have guessed that would be at least one. But if there are no ways to do that; that might be a source of horror!

Comment: If you're concerned about some sort of keyboard monitoring program, maybe you could try another approach - it probably is writing to a file somewhere (or transmitting over a network connection). Filemon could help you see if there's any suspicious file I/O, Wireshark could do the same with network traffic.

Comment: I have McAfee security suite on my laptop and I keep it updated. Hope that helps for some automatic safety.

Comment: @Kaveh Shahbazian: If the program can hook the keyboard, it could just as easily disable your security suite. IIRC, you need fairly high privileges to hook the keyboard, so if a malware app does this successfully, someone ran it as Administrator. System rooted, game over, sorry.

Comment: @Piskvor: Unless Vista/7's UAC is now preventing it, SetWindowsHookEx() can be executed at any user level.