# Detecting auto writer (keboard-hooks)

Tags: c#, keyboard-hook

I need to detect if text input was processed by keyboard or some auto writer tool (app which simulates keyboard by using keyboard hooks). Do you have any ideas or is it impossible? Thanx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465135/detecting-keyboard-hooks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Raw API discussed in a [previous StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587840/how-to-distinguish-between-multiple-input-devices-in-c) that you can leverage.

Depending on your scenario, be careful about restricting accessibility - for example screen-input devices such as tablet touchscreens, hand-writing recognition or software designed to support those with disabilities may still be legitimate input sources for your application even if the input isn't from a traditional physical keyboard.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To be exact, the app I'm developing is a typing trainer. The one problem is that "smart" students are using those autowriters which simulates key presses.