# Detect global Keyboard Hook in C3

Tags: c#, windows, keyboard-hook

It's incredibly easy to write Key-loggers in many languages. It makes me a little nervous because these small, unknown viruses won't get detected by most(read: all) antivirus'.

I'm curious how to detect if some process grabbing these keys. I want to know what process is reading my input at any given point. Kind of a Key-logger-logger.

Comment: Any program with enough privilege to install a keylogger can also attack your app and patch the call to the "detect a keylogger" API.

Comment: I'm sure that's possible and that will be my next step. Currently though I'm still searching for a way to catch keyboard hook. If you could point me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You will have to have more privilege than the keylogger. If you have the same privilege as the keylogger, then the keylogger can attack you.

Comment: @RaymondChen That's true. It's also not a problem. I will deal with persistence later, I already have a few ideas. Currently I still just need a way to detect the hook.

Comment: Have you figured this out yet?

Answer (score 0):

several answers available on these questions

- [List of installed windows hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564987/list-of-installed-windows-hooks)
- [Detecting Keyboard Hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465135/detecting-keyboard-hooks)
- [what are the methods to find hooked functions and apis](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17904/what-are-the-methods-to-find-hooked-functions-and-apis)